# Expected memory footprint of numbers vs alphanumerics in Tcl

Tags: string, tcl, numeric, alphanumeric, memory-footprint

It is aid that in Tcl, "everything is a string". But then again, it is not exactly 100% exactly like that (hence the shimmering effect). My question is this: let us say that I have, in a list, the following values:

```
list "12" 14 2a "1a"
```

My expectation, that, if "everything is a string", the memory allocated for all 4 elements should be identical (by the spec/expected behaviour), as we are looking at 4 instances of strings which length is 2.
Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: I should hope so, since the quotes are stripped off before the command gets its arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values will probably start out as strings (it's not *entirely* certain that this will happen, due to the possibility of literal sharing). Let's take a close look (if you're doing this yourself, the `tcl::unsupported::representation` command is in 8.6 only and *never* modifies the object being looked at; I put a `;format x` on that first line to ensure that we don't get any surprise conversions).

```
% set value [list "12" 14 2a "1a"];format x
x
% tcl::unsupported::representation [lindex $value 0]
value is a pure string with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0x100874070, string representation "12"
% tcl::unsupported::representation [lindex $value 1]
value is a pure string with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0x1008741c0, string representation "14"
% tcl::unsupported::representation [lindex $value 2]
value is a pure string with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0x100874c40, string representation "2a"
% tcl::unsupported::representation [lindex $value 3]
value is a pure string with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0x1008743d0, string representation "1a"
% tcl::unsupported::representation $value
value is a list with a refcount of 4, object pointer at 0x100874910, internal representation 0x1008eb050:0x0, string representation "12 14 2a 1a"
```

So yes, those values are pretty much the same. There's no internal representation of any of them, and the string representation each is using is a buffer that was allocated to be 3 bytes long (one for each character, and one for a terminating NUL byte). However, the list itself has a string representation (as well as its internal list rep) despite not being asked for one; that's because you're using a list of literals and Tcl's compiler optimises that to a single literal as that's usually the Right Thing To Do.

Comment: Once the numeric value is requested, the internal representation will be also present. For “small” integers, that's stored directly in the Tcl_Obj structure itself and so incurs no extra storage cost.